# Как правильно заменять имя существительное местоимением?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Меня на одном форуме угораздило написать фразу: "Такие задачки нынче задают одиннадцатиклассникам — и они как-то выживают!" И  мне было сделано замечание: непонятно, дескать, одиннадцатиклассники выживают или задачи. Сделавший замечание прав? Эту фразу действительно можно понять неправильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Местоимение по умолчанию относится к последнему слову своего числа и рода.

Соответственно здесь "они" воспринимается здесь как относящееся к одиннадцатиклассникам, выживание которых к тому же выглядит гораздо логичнее, чем задач, что скорее могут "остаться" и т.п.

Comment: Спасибо! «Местоимение по умолчанию относится к последнему слову своего числа и рода» — я, собственно, и сам так думал. Хочу только заметить, что и это не строго. «Тому примеров тьму» в литературе, в т. ч. классической, мы встретим — вот один: «Если б не эта тарелка [не убранная после вчерашнего ужина. — Е.С.], да не прислоненная к постели только что выкуренная трубка, или не сам хозяин, лежащий на ней...» — на трубке?)) (И. А. Гончаров, «Обломов».)

Comment: Хотите поглядеть, что мне ответили на том форуме после ссылки на ваш ответ?))) «Я пишу, что возможно приведённое вами предложение содержит ошибку, что не имею ничего против, если вы так не считаете. Не считаете и не считаете, ничего страшного. Сам же я определяю такие случаи всегда как ошибку, в данном случае хотя бы потому что в борьбе студентов и задач выживают или задачи, или студенты. Если выживают задачи — студенты не выживают, если задачи не выживают — выживают студенты».